# Removing gap between Li's in block grid in Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: zurb-foundation

i am a newbie to Foundation.
here is the thumb list i have made for a demo

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="large-12 columns">
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
  <ul class="small-block-grid-4">
    <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>

  </ul>

</div>
```

Now the thumbs are fine but it has some maybe margin or padding. the gap between each thumb.
**how can i remove that with css.**
thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define  a css

```
   .imagelist li{
            Padding:0;
            margin:0;
}
```

and add the css class "imagelist" to your ul tag, it overrides the foundation css styles.

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="imagelist large-12 columns">
     <h1>Gallery</h1>
     <ul  class="imagelist small-block-grid-4">
      <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
      <li><img src="img/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the best way to to this would be use the variables provided to you by Foundation. Check your settings.scss and you'll find a handful of variables related to the block grid. The one you're looking for specifically is on line 166: $block-grid-default-spacing. Here, you can set it to whatever you like.

Comment: This assumes you have installed Sass (and Ruby, and Node.js, etc., etc.). Seems overkill if you just want to remove a bit of spacing...

Comment: Totally overkill and not useful in case you just want to change for one place. Accepted answer is best solution.